# Groovy built-in sorting method vs spaceship operator

Tags: sorting, groovy, closures

Groovy's lists has a sort() method to which you can provide a criterion by which to sort the collection. For example:

```
def foo = ["abc", "de", "fghi"]
println foo.sort { it.size() }
```

displays "[de, abc, fghi]".
I thought that this mechanism under the hood calls the Java's method with the spaceship operator, because the following code snippets displays the same result:

```
def foo = ["abc", "de", "fghi"]
def bar = ["abc", "de", "fghi"]
println foo.sort { it }
println bar.sort { a, b -> a <=> b }
```

However, this is not the case, because:

```
def someDate = new Wrapper(new Date())
def someString = new Wrapper("16")
def someNumber = new Wrapper(4)
def foo = [someDate, someString, someNumber]
def bar = [someDate, someString, someNumber]
println foo.sort { it.value } // Produces "valid" output: [4, 16, Wed Jun 01..]
println foo.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value} // Throws ClassCastException

//Simmulates JSON object I am working with
class Wrapper {
  Object value
  Object value2
  Wrapper(value) {
    this.value = value
  }

  @Override
  String toString() {
    return value
  }
}
```

So, how does it really work? Is there any way I can get such a Groovish comparator used in sort parameter and tune it a bit (for example, so that I can sort by the value of field value2 in the second order)?

Comment: first of all it sounds wired when you try to sort items of different types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using `sort{x->...}` with one param then [`OrderBy` comparator](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/290cd3f72f381bb2752a14595b1245af81f67c26/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L9503) is used.

as for me the result is unpredictable when you have different types in the same list.

just try to run and predict the output for the following script:

```
println( ['xx', new Date(), 1199999999].sort{it} )
println( ['xx', new Date(), 11999999999].sort{it} )
```

however if you want to use it:

```
println foo.toSorted ( new OrderBy([{it.value},{it.value2}]) )
```

Comment: "as for me groovy native comparator is unpredictable for different types" - What is it that you mean by native comparator?

Comment: could you predict the result of this command: `['xx',new Date(),1199999999].sort{it}` ? then add another `9` at the end of number and run it again - i can't guess the result ;)

Comment: I can't either.  I wasn't asking if it was intuitive or predictable.  I am asking what it is.

Comment: i know - rephrased my answer :) appreciate it.